# What is happening here? Obfuscated post data?

Tags: post, response, packets

Today I was pentesting an app. When sniffing the post data being sent this is what is shown: 
[post data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efbaq.png)

I've never seen this before nor know how this is handled. The response looks something like the picture provided. Anybody mind shining some light onto this topic?

Comment: This is probably binary data, not text

Comment: Is there any way to analyze this data? @YuvalBen-Arie